# React.js import font-awesome is not working with npm

Tags: html, reactjs, font-awesome

I want to use font-awesome in my project, after install this package via npm I want to import it into main component index.js.

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

I have tried to import scss instead of css and still not working.

Later I'm trying to use in some other components:

```
<i className='fas fa-heart' />
```

And I'm getting rectangles instead of heart icons.

I have used: `npm i font-awesome` to install

In console I have no errors. How to fix this ?? With CDN is working but I don't want to use this in index.html, I want to install it and import.

Comment: Try https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome, it's specifically made for use with react

Comment: But how is that possible, that I'm teaching from course and on his pc is working on my not

Comment: Maybe you've imported an old version of font-awesome and maybe it works with `className='fa fa-heart'` instead of `className='fas fa-heart'`. Nothing else comes in my mind as the css are applied as expected in my apps

Comment: Looool... Why fa is working but they have fas in their documentation ??

Comment: Yeah I see... I've installed 4.7.0 version with npm and on site is over 5.0.0... Many thanks for poiting me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your question and I had the same problem. I summary the comment in a answer:

- **font-awesome** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome) is a old non-official library. This version is v4.7.0.
- **@fortawesome** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome) is the official repository for React Library.

In the other hand...

```html
<i className='fas fa-heart' />
```

this HTML is for the actual version of font-awesome, because it uses `fas` despite of `fa`.